# p = p + 1 is not working?

Tags: excel, copying, vba

Hopefully a quick questions. The code below works like I need it to, however, it does not seem to copy the row to the other sheet. In fact... excel seems to not do anything about the p = p + 1. I am sure its an easy mistake made but I cannot seem to find the problem. Any ideas on why that may not be happening? Very much appreciated.

```
Sub Pending(): Dim wp As Worksheet, wa As Worksheet, a As Long, p As String
Set wp = Sheets("Pending"): Set wa = Sheets("Projects"):
p = Application.Max(3, wp.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
For a = 5 To wa.UsedRange.Rows.Count

If wa.Range("Q" & a) = "Move" Then
wa.Range("A" & a).Resize(1, 19).Value = wa.Range("A" & p).Resize(1, 19).Value
wp.Range("A" & p) = "": p = p + 1:

End If
Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Are you sure you don't have *a* and *p* backwards in at least two places?

Comment: why tag [tag:google-spreadsheet]?

Comment: I recommend to format and indent your code nicely and correctly and not to use colons `:` instead of line breaks. This makes your code just more confusing and less readable. Better readability makes your code easier to maintain and to debug which results in less issues.

Comment: I was able to figure this out. It was due to me confusing certain parts of the code as you pointed out. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably go to the next line after the colon.
Change this:

```
wp.Range("A" & p) = "": p = p + 1:
```

To this:

```
wp.Range("A" & p) = "":
p = p + 1:
```

Sorry for the mistake earlier

Comment: I do not actually see the 'To this:' in the post. Apologies.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that

Comment: Well, these 2 examples are technically exactly the same. A colon is just a replace for a line break. Pretty useless to add another line break as it won't change anything.